# About Libre Office Writer getting slow in Debian

Tags: debian, libreoffice

I have recently installed Linux Debian and I have copied from an old windows-xp pc some .doc(word documents) archives. When I first opened them, they ran smoothly-just fine.

1) When I changed them to .odt the libre office writer started getting very slow, it was taking time to delete some letters or to write some new in the text. I 've solved this problem at first by saving the file with different name, then saving it as .doc. The program then seemed to work fine again.

2) When I saved the writing and went on to continue adding new text, the same problem started again- the program get's very slow.

So, the question:

What causes this malfunction and, is there a way to deal permanently with it?

Thank you.